# Android Studio getting laggy when type on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: performance, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

I have used Ubuntu `16.04`. Android studio application getting much slower but other application working normal .And I have installed android studio in bin folder.

**Configuration :** 
Hard Disk : `ssd 128Gb` , Processor : `core i3` , RAM : `8GB`

so what's would be the issue on my side?